# Android: Parse API response in field1=value1&field2=value2 format

Tags: android, parsing, retrofit, response

An API I'm calling using a non-json format. In the response, I get something like this.

```
field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3
```

What is this format called? It looks exactly like what you would send in a query usually. I would like to parse this response using Retrofit.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an extension function to parse it into a map. After that it's easy to grab the fields by doing `map["field1]` for example.

```
fun String.parseQueryFormat() : Map<String, String>{
    val queryPairs: MutableMap<String, String> = LinkedHashMap()
    val pairs = this.split("&").toTypedArray()
    for (pair in pairs) {
        val idx = pair.indexOf("=")
        queryPairs[URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(0, idx), "UTF-8")] = URLDecoder.decode(pair.substring(idx + 1), "UTF-8")
    }
    return queryPairs
}
```

.

```
val responseString = responseBody.string()
val map = responseString.parseQueryFormat()
val field1 = map["field1"]
val field2 = map["field2"]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called `query`. Only the `value` part is you need to configure.

```
@GET("link/anything")
suspend fun getTripDetail(
    @Query("value1") value1: String,
    @Query("value2") value2: String,
    @Query("value3") value3: String,
): Response<TripDetailResponse>
```

Comment: Yes sorry, maybe I wasn't clear, I know this is a query when sending a request to an API. But I was getting this as a response in the body instead of json, and I wasn't sure if there was an easy way to parse it. I ended up finding a solution, I'm posting it now.